# When testing a Website on a local development server, Firefox won't send a cookie from the server back to the server. How to fix?

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, proxy

I have a React app and a Flask app, both running on development servers on ports 3000 and 500 respectively, but being piped through Apache Web Server via reverse proxy so that the React app is on 127.0.0.1 and the Flask app is on 127.0.0.1/flaskapp.

In my Windows 11 hosts file, I have myapptest.app set to forward to 127.0.0.1.

When I log in to the React app via `https://myapptest.app`, the Flask app sends an HTTPOnly cookie to the browser, which is to be used in all future API requests. However, future requests sent by JavaScript's Fetch API do not include this cookie even with "credentials" set to "include," so the Flask app returns "401 Unauthorized." I know all this because the network logs indicate Firefox received a cookie from the login page of the Flask app and did not send this cookie in the second request.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but the entire range from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.255 is local, i.e., stays on the NIC card, and each is distinct, separate IP addresses.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: changing the hostname to point to 127.0.0.2 didn't help